# Não preencher campo se este não existir

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Tenho uma dúvida de como fazer fazer uma pergunta à base de dados.

Suponhamos que eu tenho duas tabelas com estruturas um pouco diferentes

---

**Tabela1**

```
id      tipoA    data
0        A       '21/12/14'
```

---

**Tabela2**

```
id      tipoB    data
1        B       '24/12/14'
```

---

**Resultado**

```
id      tipoA    tipoB    data
0        A         B      '21/12/14'
1        A         B      '24/12/14'
```

---

**O esperado**

```
   id      tipoA    tipoB    data
    0        A         0      '21/12/14'
    1        0         B      '24/12/14'
```

Eu simplesmente quero que se o campo não existir para não o preencher ou colocar um 0 ou ''

Eu fiz:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela1, tabela2;
```

mas esse comando não retorna o resultado esperado. Como eu deveria fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `UNION` e fazer 2 selects, exemplo:

```
SELECT id, tipoA, 0 as tipoB, data FROM tabela1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 0 as tipoA, tipoB, data FROM tabela2
```

### [SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01dea/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

Use a função **Coalesce** ou **IsNull** se for SQL. Se for MySQL use **IFNull**.

`Select id, coalesce(tipoA, 0) as tipoA, coalesce(tipoB, 0) as tipoB From tabela1, tabela2`

Mas é bom dar uma reestruturada na base de dados. Você vai ter muitos problemas iguais.

Comment: If fiz `Select id, coalesce(tabela1.tipoA, 0) as tipoA, coalesce(tabela.tipoB, 0) as tipoB From tabela1, tabela2` Mas, eu penso que este comando simplesmente está a perguntar a cada tabela em separado se tem o campo nulo, e isso nunca vai acontecer.

Comment: Essa consulta funciona? Digo, se as duas tabelas têm os campos `id` e `data`, o MySQL vai engasgar porque as referências a `id` e `data` são ambíguas.

Comment: Forcei o erro na query.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você for criar uma tabela, realize os seguintes comando:

Create table (
id number(qt desejada),
 
Obs:varchar para nomes, int para números.

Não coloque auto-increment, nem not null nas colunas, so no id.

Comment: Eu estou a utilizar uma base dados que não foi criada por mim,  já tem alguns anitos.